# C# datagrid binding

Tags: c#, datagrid, binding

So this is my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,99,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="364" Grid.Column="1" />
```

and the binding to my viewmodel is good.

The itemssource Attributes is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<QuestionAttributeDefinition, string>>`

the class QuestionAttributeDefinition has a property Name. Now I want to show in my grid:

QuestionAttributeDefinition.Name and the string of the keyvaluepair. But when I want to show this datagrid, as it is implemented now he shows:

Domain.Questions.QuestionAttributeDefinition and the string(the string is ok)

How can I show the property 'Name' of QuestionAttributeDefinition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do define the columns yourself:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,99,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="364" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Key.Name}">
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```